# Set minimum order amount for a payment method only in frontend for a store

Tags: event-observer, configuration, payment-methods, frontend, admin-panel

I need to set the minimum order amount for a purchase order payment type only in the frontend for a particular store.

I used system/configuration/payment method/custom payment ->set minimum order to 100 for that store in the admin panel.

But this filter gets applied even when an order is placed from the admin side

I need the minimum order amount filtered only when an order is placed from the admin side.

Any thoughts will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [this](https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_AdminMoney/) module to enable/disable a certain method of payment when a condition applies (in this case, to enable Money order only in the admin). You can fork it and modify it as you want to match the criteria you need. Key is in the Observer.php file where the logic you need to modify resides.

Comment: I added a new field named 'Enable filter in admin' in the store config for Purchase order and used an observer to monitor the payment event and based on the values set in the store config i show the payment method when an order is being placed in the admin. Thanks for pointing me to right direction.

Comment: Amazing! Fork the extension and publish it for the community if you have some time!

Comment: Hi I am setting $result->isAvailable = true, and found while debugging that it is setting the paymethod to true but still the payment is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$event= $observer->getEvent();
$method= $event->getMethodInstance();
$result= $event->getResult();
$quoteObj=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$totals = $quoteObj->getTotals(); //Total object
$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue());
```

//use business logic .below am disabling the payment method if cart subtotal is less than 250

if($subtotal<=250){
                 $cardonly = true;
                 //set message if subtotal <250$ in cart
                        if($method->getName() == "checkmo"){
                 $result->isAvailable = false;}}

Comment: please dont add the direct code, just add atleast one bit of line of explanation in words.

Answer (score 0):

I found while debugging that it is setting the payment method to true but still the payment is not getting displayed. My code is as follows

```
public function poPaymentFilterIsActive($observer)
{
    $instance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
    if ($instance->getCode() == "purchaseorder")
    {
        //if the Purchase order payment method is active
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/purchaseorder/active',$observer->getQuote()->getStoreId()) == "1")
        {
            $result = $observer->getResult();
            //If the order is being placed from the admin
            if ((Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()))
            {
                //If the flag Apply Filters in Admin? is set to No
                if(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/purchaseorder/admin_filter',$observer->getQuote()->getStoreId()) == "0")
                {
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In config.xml

```
<events>
   <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                    <My_checkout>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>My_checkout/Observer</class>
                        <method>poPaymentFilterIsActive</method>
                    </My_checkout>
                </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
```

Am I doing something wrong?